# Use Javascript to Make Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, calculator

Good Day - I am Learning Javascript, I am trying to create a Calculator to calculate ampere-turn to magnetize a tool (it's related to my job.) I am trying to use some formulas to calculate this ampere-turn. The code seems fine to me, but it's not working. I put some values in the form, and click button submit, but no result found and i don't know why this happens.

I am sharing my code here for your kind review. and help me to fix this problem.
thank you.

```js
function ampereturn()
{
    
    var inputOD = Number(document.ampereturn.inputod.value);
    var inputLen = Number(document.ampereturn.inputlen.value);
    var InputID = Number(document.ampereturn.Inputid.value);
    var InputTurn = Number(document.ampereturn.Inputturn.value);
    var ans;
  
    
    var ldratio = inputLen/inputOD;
    var coilradius = InputID/2;
    var toolradius = inputOD/2;
    var pi = 3.14;
    
    var xcoil = (coilradius * coilradius) * pi;
    var xtool = (toolradius * toolradius) * pi;
    
    var factor = xtool/xcoil;
    var text = "Use Intermediate Fill-factor formula:";
    
    if(factor >= 0.5)
        {
            ans = 35000/(ldratio+2)*Inputturn;
            document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = ans;
        }
    
    if(factor <= 0.1)
        {
            ans = 45000/ldratio*Inputturn;
            document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = ans;
        }
    else
        {
            document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = text;
        }
}
```

```html
<form name="ampereturn">
  
  <div class="w3-half w3-margin-top">
    <label>Tool OD:</label>
    <input id="inputod" class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Input Tool Outer Dia:">
  </div>
        
  <div class="w3-half w3-margin-top">
    <label>Tool Lenght:</label>
    <input id="inputlen" class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Input Tool Length">
  </div>
                            
                            
  <div class="w3-half w3-margin-top">
    <label>Coil ID:</label>
    <input id="Inputid" class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Input Coil Internal Dia:">
  </div>
                            
  <div class="w3-half w3-margin-top">
    <label>Coil Turn:</label>
    <input id="Inputturn" class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Input Number of turn in coil:">
  </div>
                            
 <div class="w3-half w3-margin-top">
    <label>Required Ampere:</label>
   <p id="sum"></p>
  </div>
                   
<button type="button" onclick="ampereturn()">Submit</button>   
</form>
<br><hr>
```

thank you in advance. ....

Comment: What do you mean specifically by “Its not working”?

Comment: I put some value, and click button "Submit", and found no result.

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: ampereturn is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 39,
  "colno": 46
}

Comment: *it's not working* is a useless problem description. How **specifically** does it *not work**? Please spend a few minutes reading [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change the function name which is same as the form name.
- Change Inputturn to InputTurn in the if condition.

Required Code:

```
function Ampereturn()
{
var inputOD = Number(document.ampereturn.inputod.value);
var inputLen = Number(document.ampereturn.inputlen.value);
var InputID = Number(document.ampereturn.Inputid.value);
var InputTurn = Number(document.ampereturn.Inputturn.value);
var ans;
var ldratio = inputLen/inputOD;
var coilradius = InputID/2;
var toolradius = inputOD/2;
var pi = 3.14;   
var xcoil = (coilradius * coilradius) * pi;
var xtool = (toolradius * toolradius) * pi;
var factor = xtool/xcoil;
var text = "Use Intermediate Fill-factor formula:";
if(factor >= 0.5)
    {
        ans = 35000/(ldratio+2)*InputTurn;
        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = ans;
    }
 else if(factor <=0.1)
    {
        ans = 45000/ldratio*InputTurn;
        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = ans;
    }
else
    {
        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```